# How to avoid displaying duplicate values in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query in which I try to display the most frequent trip between two stations by the day of the week:

```
SELECT startday AS Day, start_station_name, start_station_id, end_station_name, end_station_id, count(*) AS trip_counts
FROM table
GROUP BY startday, start_station_name, end_station_name, start_station_id, end_station_id
ORDER BY trip_counts DESC
```

AND this is my current output:

[image]

I don't want rows with the same 'day' to repeat, I just want to display the one with the larger trip_count by day.
Row 8 should not be displayed, since row 1 has value 'Monday' already and its value for trip_count is larger.

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT startday AS Day, start_station_name, start_station_id,
             end_station_name, end_station_id, 
             COUNT(*) AS trip_counts,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY startday ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table
      GROUP BY startday, start_station_name, end_station_name, start_station_id, end_station_id
     ) s
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY trip_counts DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply turn your query to a view (so it would be easier to access next time):

```
CREATE VIEW view_name
AS
SELECT startday AS Day, start_station_name, start_station_id, end_station_name, end_station_id, COUNT(*) AS trip_counts
FROM table
GROUP BY startday, start_station_name, end_station_name, start_station_id, end_station_id
ORDER BY trip_counts DESC
```

Then you can easily use the query below to access only the entries with max trip_counts:

```
SELECT *, MAX(trip_counts) trip_counts
FROM vw_name
GROUP BY day
```